# how to build an email functionality in Node js?

Tags: node.js

I need to build an api for email integration for every client (like yahoo,gmail,outlook) using same api. For gmail I have used nodemailer. And in that I am using refresh token for security. And in that also I am able to integrate email for only one user. I need to send emails to the user and also they can reply to that same email.

Anyone know any clue how to do this. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Using outlook Graph API, you can able to fetch outlook emails for a specific account. The same way you use Gmail API for fetching their emails. Now if you want to send emails you need an SMTP host otherwise, you can use outlook/Gmail SMTP host respectively.
N.B: maybe outlook has limitations. They only support paid domain service

Comment: Is there any one Api for all these service which provides security also?